# How to get URL of mp3 when it is playing

Tags: java, android, download, mp3

We can play mp3 files from browsers, Social Networks, Apps... I want to get URL of mp3 when it's playing. One way here is to create an extension in the browser. But in other apps we can't. Here is an example: 
I go to some site and open some mp3:

[image: mp3 from sote]

If you can see the music is playing and it has a URL. I want to get this URL when music starts playing. How can I do that? And how can I get URL of music which is playing in some app? Is it possible?

Comment: What have you tried to play your mp3? I mean, if you’re playing mp3 you should have it’s url or file path in your storage already otherwise you won’t be able to play any mp3.

Comment: @JaswantSingh We can play mp3 from web sites, apps (for example VK, Facebook ...), not only from storage

Comment: If you’re using Facebook or YouTube as your source, it won’t be possible to get the url of the mp3 as these sites don’t reveal the source plus, it’s not legal to download these mp3s. Afaik

Comment: @JaswantSingh, Got it, What about browsers?

Comment: If you’ve noticed, some websites don’t reveal the url (source) due to privacy and other stuff while some websites do, and to get the url from those websites you’ll need to parse the complete HTML (DOM)page to look for the audio source, by using some kind of regex to find the pattern.

Comment: @DIlshodK from browsers you can easily get, let me know if you want it.

Comment: @VishwaRatna, I want, Could you give some examples?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If you can see the music is playing and it has a URL. I want to get
>   this URL when music starts playing. How can I do that?

If you are loading the website into a `WebView`, the easiest possible way you can get the URL by intercept the requests through `WebViewClient` and check if the URL contains '.mp3'. See the following example,

```
public class YourWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public WebResourceResponse shouldInterceptRequest(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
            String url = request.getUrl().toString();
            if (url.contains(".mp3")) {
                Log.d(TAG, "MP3 url = [" + url + "]");
            }
            return super.shouldInterceptRequest(view, request);
        }
}
```

> And how can I get URL of music which is playing in some app? Is it
>   possible?

Yes possible but not too easy especially if you are going to get it from SSL traffic. To sniff other app's network traffic you need to perform [MITM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack). There are a couple of apps in the play store which are doing exactly the same thing. You can look into [HttpCanary](https://github.com/MegatronKing/HttpCanary) app for reference. Basically you need to perform the following steps -

1. Set up a proxy server
2. Configure your device to pass its network traffic to that proxy server
3. Ask the proxy server to give you the network data
4. Analyze the network data to see if it contains 'mp3' URL

If you need to intercept https traffic, you need to generate and install an SSL certificate.

Answer (score 1):

First import the JSOUP library from maven

```
compile 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.12.1'
```

after that use this code

```
            Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
            System.out.println(doc.title());
            Elements h1s = doc.select(".jp-type-single"); 
            System.out.println("Number of results: " + h1s.size());
            for (Element element : h1s) { 
            String mp3Url = element.attr("data-xc-filepath"); 
            System.out.println("mp3 url: " + mp3Url);
            file_num++;
            URLConnection conn = new URL(mp3Url).openConnection();
            InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
            OutputStream outstream = new FileOutputStream(new 
            File("/users/pelican/downloads/"+file_num+"file.mp3"));
            byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
            int len;
            while ((len = is.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                outstream.write(buffer, 0, len);
            }
```

now let me explain this 
JSOUP fetched the webpage using your HTML URL

after that, it converts into doc

and after that, it selects the element by using a select method and here we are getting the first audio tag that we want to search.

Answer (score 0):

As the tip above of intercepting the requests, I went to the Network tab on the browser console and found what I want it.

Using Google Chrome, just inspect the page and go to the network tab. The audio link is there. Just click on the line that you think it is (the ones that has *.mp3, *.wav etc) and the browser will open the audio on a new tab, with the full link

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).